# Swift: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'Int'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this piece of code that is supposed to increment the score of a Firebase variable by one whenever a user taps on a message:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    super.collectionView(collectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let data = self.messages[indexPath.row]

    print("They tapped: "  + (data.text) + "- " + (data.senderDisplayName))

    rootRef.child("messages").child(data.senderId).child("score").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        // Set value and report transaction success
        currentData.value = currentData.value + 1
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

However I am getting the error `No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'` at the line

```
currentData.value = currentData.value + 1
```

for some reason which I cannot figure out.

I tried casting as an Integer as such `currentData.value = currentData.value + 1 as! Int` as well as `currentData.value as! Int = currentData.value + 1` but Swift doesn't it (it says `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'Int'`)

If anybody could help me fix this type error, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
currentData.value  = currentData.value as! Int + 1
```

as currentData.value is of type optional AnyObject you'll have to cast it as Int

Comment: I tried your code but it crashed my program with the error: `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x19fe50bc0) to 'NSNumber' (0x19fe5b900).`

Comment: please make a check before it if your value is having some value or not?
and if it is having what kind of value it is having NSNumber/Int/NSInteger?

Comment: please let me know your data type

Answer (score 1):

> currentData.value = *currentData.value* + **1 as! Int**

Here you cast '1' as an int, so currentData.value still has an unknown type

> **currentData.value as! Int** = *currentData.value* + 1

Here you cast the variable you are assigning data to as an int, but the thing you are adding to 1 still has an unknown type

Try this out:

```
if let myValue = currentData.value as? Int{
    currentData.value = myValue + 1
    return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it doesn't update data with Firebase. Setting data should happen with the subsequent line: `return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)` however that isn't working...I tried replacing currentData with myValue but Swift doesn't recognize it because it is out of scope.

Comment: You can throw the return inside the if. I've updated the code to reflect this. Make sure you handle the else case though

Comment: Hm. It said `Missing return in a closure expected to return 'FIRTransactionResult'` so I added the code `else {
                return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
            }` and it worked but still did not update with Firebase...

Comment: Your else case is an error case, meaning that iOS was not successful in getting an Int from currentData.value. You need to figure out why, which is what I meant by "Make sure you handle the else case". If you simply return in your else case, it means that if you fail to get a value, you're just going to return the old value

Answer (score 0):

The data value you are retrieving could be one of many types, Firebase supports setting this to a NSNumber, String, Dictionary, Array,etc  (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_mutable_data)

Conversely when you get the value,  you need to help Swift understand what specific type it is by casting it to NSNumber and getting the intValue from that.  AnyObject to too generic to do operations like '+'

If you are sure that the value will always be an NSNumber you should be able to do:

```
currentData.value = (currentData.value as! NSNumber).intValue + 1
```

Otherwise you should check the type first and act accordingly.

If you put this code in a playground,  it produces the expected result, 6:

```
import Foundation
let myValue: AnyObject? = NSNumber(value: 5)
let addIt = (myValue as! NSNumber).intValue + 1
print("\(addIt)")
```

Comment: I replaced my code with the code you recommended and got the following error show up: `No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'`

Comment: You must have something else going on, I just tried it in a playground and it works.   Hmm.   I will update my answer with my Playground code.